# Docker compose and Spring Boot Config server

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

I have a working spring boot web application that gets its configuration properties from spring boot config server.  My application has 3 environments - dev, qa and prod.  In my resources folder I have 3 files bootstrap-dev.properties, bootstarp-qa.properties and bootstrap-prod.properties.  A sample bootstrap file is shown below

```
spring.application.name=MyApp
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://my.config.server
spring.cloud.config.label=feature-branch-101
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

What content do I need to put in my docker-compose file which can read configurations from spring boot configuration server and support 3 different environments.  Does anyone have samples?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the guys at [JHispter](https://jhipster.github.io/) do it (see files below)

I think the trick is at the `app.yml` file where you set which profile you want to run for your environment for your app.  Like this:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
```

So, from then on, it is the `application.yml` and `bootstrap.yml` that know which environment properties to load into SpringBoot

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    DELAY_SLEEP=0 \
    JAVA_OPTS=""

# add directly the war
ADD *.war /app.war

EXPOSE 8080
CMD echo "The application will start in ${DELAY_SLEEP}s..." && \
    sleep ${DELAY_SLEEP} && \
    java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app.war
```

**app.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
    my-app:
        image: myapp
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://my-app-mysql:3306/my-app?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - DELAY_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    my-app-mysql:
        extends:
            file: mysql.yml
            service: my-app-mysql
```

**mysql.yml** (if needed)

```
version: '2'
services:
    my-app-mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.18
        # volumes:
        #     - ~/volumes/my-app/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/
        environment:
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=my-app
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl --character_set_server=utf8 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
    application:
        name: my-app
    profiles:
        # The commented value for `active` can be replaced with valid Spring profiles to load.
        # Otherwise, it will be filled in by maven when building the WAR file
        # Either way, it can be overridden by `--spring.profiles.active` value passed in the commandline or `-Dspring.profiles.active` set in `JAVA_OPTS`
        active: #spring.profiles.active#
    cloud:
        config:
            fail-fast: false # if not in "prod" profile, do not force to use Spring Cloud Config
            uri: http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/config
            # name of the config server's property source (file.yml) that we want to use
            name: MyApp
            profile: dev # profile(s) of the property source
            label: master # toggle to switch to a different version of the configuration as stored in git
            # it can be set to any label, branch or commit of the config source git repository
```

Comment: I would recommend updating Compose files to the latest version instead of version 2. Here's the [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) file documentation.